# Create view to allow certain fields - SQL

Tags: sql, concatenation

My table includes FName,LName,StudentID,Major1,Major2,Minor 
I am attempting to create 2 different CREATE VIEW tables with different restrictions. For the first one, my view table would need to show me the names of all the students that are majoring in certain business classes. How would I be able to get my query to include for example - ECO, FIN, ACC but it would not include non-business majors for example BIO, CHEM.

```
CREATE VIEW A7T6 AS
SELECT FName || ' ' || LName AS "STUDENT", STUDENTID AS "ID", GPA, Upper(MINOR) as "MINOR"
FROM A7
```

What would my WHERE statement be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question includes two major columns "Major1" and "Major2", you might require a minor modification to GurV's script.  e.g.:

```
create view A7T6
as
select FName || ' ' || LName as "STUDENT",
    STUDENTID as "ID",
    GPA,
    Upper(MINOR) as "MINOR"
from A7
where major1 in ('ECO', 'FIN', 'ACC')
or major2 in ('ECO', 'FIN', 'ACC');
```

For the non-business case, it might be better to alter the WHERE clause to use NOT IN rather than enumerate all possible negative cases:

```
where major1 not in ('ECO', 'FIN', 'ACC')
and major2 not in ('ECO', 'FIN', 'ACC');
```